# Laravel Get Days In Month From Month Number?

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

In Laravel Application I have month number like 01, 02, 03 upto 12.
I want to get all days in this month.
I cannot use **daysInMonth()** as I do not have a date all I have is month number.

```
Carbon::now()->daysInMonth();
```

how can I make this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do so

```
Carbon::now()->month($month_number)->daysInMonth;

// ...

Carbon::now()->month(02)->daysInMonth; // 28
```

Comment: Thanks...and is there a way I can get dates of that month?
like in sequence?

Comment: If you mean start and end dates you can use `->startOfMonth()` and `->endOfMonth()`, use `->toDateTimeString()` to format date for a readable format.

Comment: oh no...in fact I need labels for my chart...like all they days from 1 to 30 or 31

Comment: I think just a simble loop will be enough like, `range(1, Carbon::now()->month(02)->daysInMonth)` this will return an array starting from 1 till end of month.

Comment: Thank You Very Much

Comment: [CarbonPeriod](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period) is also a way to get dates of a given interval between two dates

Comment: There is a problem here if you run now on a 31 days month (like today), and then call month() with a non 31 days month you will get an overlap. i.e:

`Carbon\Carbon::now()->month(2)`

will return "2022-03-03" and you will be getting the days of the month of March.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
Carbon::createFromDate(null, $number_of_month, 1)->daysInMonth;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    return getDaysInMonth('March');
    return getDaysInMonth(3, false);

});

function getDaysInMonth($month, $monthName = true): int
{

    $today = Carbon::now();

    $monthNames = [
        'January' => 1, 'February' => 2, 'March' => 3, 'April' => 4,
        'May' => 5, 'June' => 6, 'July' => 7, 'August' => 8,
        'September' => 9, 'October' => 10, 'November' => 11, 'December' => 12,
    ];

    if($monthName)
        return $today->month($monthNames[$month])->daysInMonth;

    return $today->month($month)->daysInMonth;

}
```

Comment: Hi, maybe could you add some explanations about your code before your answer.